# Android MediaRecorder delay and method of fixing it

Tags: android, delay, mediarecorder

I am developing an app that allows you to record many clips and stitches them back together before uploading. Whilst developing for Android 5 and up I think this is prevalent problem on all the platforms. Not sure if anyone came up with an usable solution. I seem not to be able to record 1s video as the MediaRecorder takes ~500ms to .start() and on different devices this time changes.

The only method that I found to be more or less accurate is to set up a file observer on media file at the moment when I start() and stop observing when I finish I tend to wait for the first 256bytes to be written before I measure the clip time.

**Now then CAN ANYONE tell me whether this is the only thing I can do? Or is there a better method of measuring the delay? Or if you know of an approach I could take to write a recording app that will have immediate start and stop I will greatly appreciate that.**

If not maybe point me in the direction of a different approach? Bear in mind I am an absolute beginner so answers like "use MediaCodec API" really not going to help me a lot. I searched for days an appropriate solution  can't seem to find anything useful anywhere. Setting thread with a delayedPost is also not an answer.

Comment: Are you able to find any solution for this?